# Trouble resizing view in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

I am having trouble resizing my view in XCode (5.1.1). I have a storyboard and one of my views I am not able to resize. It is a table view and I was able to resize it but once I set the transitions on the table views I am no longer able to resize it. I have even tried to delete all of the segues and I still am not able to. This seems to be a common problem I have. This is not the only view I am having trouble resizing. I also am not able to resize a view that has been copied and pasted.

I have tried checking and unchecking (Resize View from NIB), and I know how to resize the board (set it to freeform and change the size in the size inspector of the view). As I said, these have worked before but they seem to just stop working. I have also tried changing the simulated metrics. Is there something I am missing or doing that makes it stop working? I am trying to do this on the visual side, not coded, as this is for me to add content to the views.

Comment: Please provide some code or screenshot.

Comment: I've had this before and it appeared to be an Xcode bug, the only ways I managed to solve it was to either to delete and re-create the views in question or delete the whole view controller and re-do it from scratch, then the problem disappeared.

Comment: I can provide screenshots but I am not sure what screenshots to provide? Is there anything you had in mind?

Also yes I have notice that it works if I redo it, I was just wondering if there was something I was doing wrong where I wouldn't have to do this